I want to create a regular expression for password security rules
When creating a password, I want to check if the input value meets the conditions.
rules are as follows:

Length of 9 characters or more and 20 characters or less, excluding spaces

Include at least 1 number, uppercase letter, lowercase letter, and special character.


The regular expression for that rule was created as follows. And it works well.
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{9,20}$
Example)

Uppercase + lowercase + number + special character, OK

Lowercase + number + special character, NO


However, a problem arose at the step of lowering the security level by one level.
The changed rules are as follows:

Length of 9 characters or more and 20 characters or less, excluding spaces

Must include at least 3 of the following: numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and special characters.


Example)
- Uppercase + lowercase + numbers + special characters, OK
- Lowercase + numbers + special characters, OK
- Uppercase + lowercase + numbers, OK
- Uppercase + lowercase + special characters, OK
Please help me!!
I tried making each rule separately.

Length: 9 to 20 characters excluding spaces

^[\S]{9,20}$


Excluding special characters

(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*


Excluding capital letters

(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*?[0-9]).*?[a-z].*


Excluding numbers

(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*


Excluding lowercase letters

(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*?[0-9]).*?[A-Z].*

However, I think it would be better to make them all at once by combining them like before.

See at rexegg

"I think it would be better to make them all at once by combining" - actually, no it wouldn't.

Dont. Just ensure the password is long enough. Min. 24 chars. Thats much better than this bullshit rulesets.

"and 20 characters or less"? Why would people do this? What is the reason for this decision? 20 characters is not enough for many users.

So you want to match at least 3 rules out of 4 rules, where rule 1 is 1 number, rule 2 is 1 uppercase letter, rule 3 is 1 lowercase letter, and rule 4 is 1 special character right?

Should I impose a maximum length on passwords? "Passwords are hashed to 32, 40, 128, whatever length. The only reason for a minimum length is to prevent easy to guess passwords. There is no purpose for a maximum length."

Actually, just noticed that your password will accept almost any character, include emojis or control characters. It might be better to replace .{9,20} by [\p{L}\p{N}\p{Sm}\p{Sc}\p{Sk}\p{P}]{9,32} which will accept letters in any language, numbers, some groups of symbols and punctuation with the use of Unicode classes. You may also replace [a-z] by \p{Ll} and [A-Z] by \p{Lu}, to accept "àéü" or "ÜÔ" also as valid lowercase and uppercase letters. An emoji, tab, vertical tab, or any other problematic char will not pass.

Please read this page about password validation.

You could make life easier and keep the task maintainable if you break it into parts. Check for length and then test for an array of conditions. If 3 of 4 are successfull -> passed (JS demo at tio.run)

Try:
^((?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W])|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W])|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W])|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]))[\S]{9,20}$

See: regex101

Explanation:
First the four cases are created of which condition trifecta can be valid. then the string is collected.

^: start of string
(?:...): conditions

(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W]): ensure all but capital letter
|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W]): or ensure all but lowercase letter
|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^_\W]*[_\W]): or ensure all but digit
|(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9]): or ensure all  but special


\S{9,20}$: match 9 to 20 non space chars


@CarySwoveland please try individual strings and you will see that it works. Reason for failure in your setting is that the lookaheads can look past linebreaks and assert that the (in this case) the special characters work. If this is in issue in the actual usecase please add [^...]{0,19} instead of the [^...]*

I see. If I may suggest, when you link to regex101.com you should include at least one test string. You could also modify your regex there so that it no longer gobbles up newlines. In a recent SO answer, for example, one term of a regex I proposed was (?=-[^-]*, which of course matches newlines. I modified that to (?=-[^-\n]* and after my last test string added the text, "Note: \n is only included in character classes to permit the testing of the regex against multiple strings here."

@CarySwoveland IThanks so much for your feedback! I was unsure of whether this would just "unnecessarily" clutter up the actual regex for display purposes - that's why I chose not to. I still think it is a good point you are making!

The question appears to imply that a special character is any ASCII character that is not a whitespace, digit, uppercase letter or lowercase letter.
The password passes the various tests if and only if it matches the following regular expression.
^                       # match the beginning of the string
(?:                     # begin a non-capture group
  (?=.*[^\s\dA-Za-z])   # pos lookahead asserts string contains a
                        # special character
  (?:                   # begin a non-capture group
    (?=.*\d)            # pos lookahead asserts string contains a digit
    (?=.*[A-Z])         # pos lookahead asserts string contains an UC letter
  |                     # or
    (?=.*\d)            # pos lookahead asserts string contains a digit
    (?=.*[a-z])         # pos lookahead asserts string contains a LC letter
  |                     # or
    (?=.*[A-Z])         # pos lookahead asserts string contains an UC letter
    (?=.*[a-z])         # pos lookahead asserts string contains a LC letter
  )                     # end non-capture group
|                       # or
  (?=.*\d)              # pos lookahead assert string contains a digit
  (?=.*[A-Z])           # pos lookahead asserts string contains an UC letter
  (?=.*[a-z])           # pos lookahead asserts string contains a LC letter
)                       # end non-capture group
[ ]*                    # match zero or more spaces
(?:                     # begin non-capture group
  [^ ]                  # match a char other than a space
  [ ]*                  # match zero or more spaces
)                       # end non-capture group
{9,20}                  # execute the preceeding non-capture grouip 9-20 times
$                       # match the end of the string

Demo
I have written the expression in extended (a.k.a. free-spacing) mode to make it self-documenting. In that mode comments and whitespace padding are removed by the regex engine before the expression is parsed. Action therefore be taken to retain whitespace that is not padding, here two space characters. I have chosen to protect those characters by enclosing them in a character class ([ ]). Alternatively, they could have been escaped (\ ) or certain Unicode tokens could have been used.
